# Can more bitcoins be transferred to a paper wallet address once it is created?

Tags: paper-wallet

I created a paper wallet from coinbase with some initial amount and secured it. I want to keep adding more bitcoins to the same address. Can I do that? Are there any issues doing it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can.

The wallet itself does not hold any money. It is just a private key, to which the coins will be associated.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. I have done so myself. I gave my kids paper wallets with 10 millibits each and am now giving them a bitcoin allowance of 4 millibits per month.

Comment: Cool concept for allowance